# PHP check if False or Null

Tags: php, isset

I also get confused how to check if a variable is `false`/`null` when returned from a function.

When to use `empty()` and when to use `isset()` to check the condition ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For returns from functions, you use neither `isset` nor `empty`, since those only work on variables and are simply there to test for possibly non-existing variables without triggering errors.

For function returns checking for the existence of variables is pointless, so just do:

```
if (!my_function()) {
    // function returned a falsey value
}
```

To read about this in more detail, see [The Definitive Guide To PHP's `isset` And `empty`](http://kunststube.net/isset/).

Comment: i am actually trying to catch a return array or false and trying to determine further what to do

Comment: OK? So `$return = myfunction(); if (!$return) { // 't was false! }`

Comment: @tkoom Would you be happier if the syntax was more operator-like?

Comment: @deceze, if `empty` is not a function, it'd be nice if it didn't pretend one. And it does and it confuses programmers, just as a lot of things does (see http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/)

Comment: Note that this also catches empty strings and empty arrays and 0 and '0', which might not be what you want

Answer (score 11):

Checking variable ( a few examples )

```
if(is_null($x) === true) // null
if($x === null) // null
if($x === false)
if(isset($x) === false) // variable undefined or null
if(empty($x) === true) // check if variable is empty (length of 0)
```

Comment: Your comment on `empty` not quite correct: `empty` also returns true for values that are equivalent to 0.

Comment: ToolmakerSteve is correct, the explanation of what `empty()` does is misleading for researchers.

Answer (score 6):

Isset() checks if a variable has a value including ( False , 0 , or Empty string) , But not NULL.
Returns TRUE if var exists; FALSE otherwise.

On the other hand the empty() function checks if the variable has an empty value empty string , 0, NULL ,or False. Returns FALSE if var has a non-empty and non-zero value.

Answer (score 2):

`ISSET` checks the variable to see if it has been set, in other words, it checks to see if the variable is any value except `NULL` or `not assigned a value`. ISSET returns TRUE if the variable exists and has a value other than NULL. That means variables assigned a " ", 0, "0", or FALSE are set, and therefore are TRUE for ISSET.

`EMPTY` checks to see if a variable is empty. Empty is interpreted as: " " (an empty string), 0 (0 as an integer), 0.0 (0 as a float), "0" (0 as a string), NULL, FALSE, array() (an empty array), and "$var;" (a variable declared, but without a value in a class.

Comment: A variable cannot not have an assigned value. The value is at least `null`.

Answer (score 2):

isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

```
$a = "test";
$b = "anothertest";

var_dump(isset($a));      // TRUE
var_dump(isset($a, $b)); // TRUE

unset ($a);

var_dump(isset($a));     // FALSE
```

empty — Determine whether a variable is empty

```
<?php
$var = 0;

// Evaluates to true because $var is empty
if (empty($var)) {
  echo '$var is either 0, empty, or not set at all';
}

// Evaluates as true because $var is set
if (isset($var)) {
  echo '$var is set even though it is empty';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is important to use the correct function / notation, not just whatever appears to work correctly. There are a few things to consider that are not mentioned in the existing answers.

- Use `isset` to check if a variable has either not been set or has been set to `null`.
- Use `empty` to check if a variable == false. `null` is cast to `false` and as with isset, no notice is thrown if the variable has not been set.

`if (!$variable)` or `if ($variable == false)` is the same as `empty`, except that a notice will be thrown if the variable has not been set.

`if ($variable !== null)` is the same as `isset`, except that a notice will be thrown if the variable has not been set.

**NB**

`if (!$variable)` and `if ($variable !== null)` perform better than their respective functions but not when notices are being generated, therefore, $variable needs to have been set. Don't suppress notices as a micro-optimisation, as this will make your code harder to debug and even suppressed notices cause a performance penalty.

**Coalescing operators**

If you are checking a variable so that you can assign a value to it, then you should use `??`, `?:` instead of `if` statements.

**??**

`??` assigns a value when not equal to null.
`$variable = $a ?? $b` is the same as:

```
if (isset($a))
    $variable = $a;
else
    $variable = $b;
```

**?:**

`?:` assigns a value when not == to false.
`$variable = $a ?: $b` is the same as:

```
if ($a)
    $variable = $a;
else
    $variable = $b;
```

but remember that a **notice will be generated** when $a has not been set. If $a might not have been set, you can use `$variable = !empty($a) ? $a : $b;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

- check false: if ($v === false)
- check null: if (is_null($v))

empty() is an evil.It is slow,and when $v queals **false,0,'0',array(),''**,it will return true.if you need this kind of checking,you can use **if ($v)**.

Comment: `empty` is not evil, you simply do not understand its use case. May I direct you to [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)?