# Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, helper

I have a custom helper and a config, I can get the value but when I try the isset() it's not working and it shows me like this

[image]

and this is the content of customer helper: `app\helper\LmsHelper.php`

```
class LmsHelper
{   
    private static $host;
    private static $api_key;
    private static $api_version;
    private static $use_ssl;
    private static $debug;
    private static $port;

    public function __construct() {
        self::$host         = Config::get('lms.host');
        self::$api_key      = Config::get('lms.api_key');
        self::$api_version  = Config::get('lms.api_version');
        self::$use_ssl      = Config::get('lms.use_ssl');
        self::$debug        = isset(Config::get('lms.debug')) ? Config::get('lms.debug') : false;


        if (isset(Config::get('lms.port'))) {
            self::$port = Config::get('lms.port');
        } else {
            self::$port = self::$use_ssl ? 443 : 80;
        }
    }
}
```

and `app\config\lms.php`

```
<?php

return array( 
    'host' => 'www.themartialarts.university', 
    'api_key' => '6027-178512-e272b9afac4763199fa8d79e4bc0dcb39a378658', 
    'api_version' => '1', 
    'use_ssl' => true,
);
```

any idea what other method I can do? cause this is from normal PHP and I convert it into Laravel.

Comment: I think you should not use the "isset" function, as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464714/php-check-if-false-or-null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Config::has("name")` method call since it's a method call you can't use `isset()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can only call [isset](http://php.net/isset) on $variables.

Change that line to `self::$debug = Config::get('lms.debug', false);` to solve the problem. (set the default value to false)

Answer (score 0):

The " isset " takes only variable. You must set the result of your function in a prior varriable.

```
 public function __construct() {
    $config = Config::get('lms.debug');
    self::$host         = Config::get('lms.host');
    self::$api_key      = Config::get('lms.api_key');
    self::$api_version  = Config::get('lms.api_version');
    self::$use_ssl      = Config::get('lms.use_ssl');
    self::$debug        = isset($config) ? Config::get('lms.debug') : false;

    $configPort = Config::get('lms.port');
    if (isset($configPort)) {
        self::$port = Config::get('lms.port');
    } else {
        self::$port = self::$use_ssl ? 443 : 80;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `if (isset(Config::get('lms.port'))) {`? :P

Answer (score 0):

Even if the language construct supported it, it doesn't make much sense to test whether the function returns a variable because even missing `return` clauses generate a proper `null`. E.g.:

```
function nothing() {
}

var_dump( nothing() );
```

```
NULL
```

I suspect you want to use [is_null()](http://php.net/is_null) rather than [isset()](http://php.net/isset).

Answer (score 0):

Use `if` instead of `isset` as `isset` is used to check a *variable is set and is not NULL.*